# How to get clients real IP in jsp? Special situation

Tags: jsp, ip

**My Scenario:** Client is opening `jsp2 page` window by clicking button from `jsp1 page`.

I want to get Client's IP in `jsp2 page`

I have tried to use below mentioned code:

`String clientip = request.getRemoteAddr();`

but it's getting IP of `jsp1 page`

For getting IP I can't pass parameters from `jsp1 page`.

Can anyone help me on this issue?
Your help is much appreciated.
Best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working in my case:

```
 String ip = request.getRemoteHost();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as *IP of jsp1 page* - JSP page does not have an IP address. According to `ServletRequest.getRemoteAddr()` javadoc, the method *returns the Internet Protocol (IP) address of the client or last proxy that sent the request* - i.e. if you have a proxy in front of your servlet container (e.g. Apache HTTPD), you'll get IP address of that proxy.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1767101/3511123) for how to see 'through' the proxy and get the real IP address of the client.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate your help!